# How to implement an Expandable RecyclerView where the child is having a grid structure?

Tags: android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout, expandablerecyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

I need to have an expandable view where the parent/expandable title will have a text and drop-down arrow. Children of each such title should be a view having multiple items in a grid structure. (Kind of like a recycler view with GridLayoutManager). Please find the attached image for reference. [image]

Each year corresponds to the group title, and the cover arts shown corresponds to the children.

Answer (score 0):

We will have an ExpandableListView, for which the adapter returns 1 for **getChildrenCount(int groupPosition)** and**getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition)**  returning null. And the childView for the ExpandableListView will have a recycler view. This is one way to do it. [Tried and working]

One more way could be using two RecyclerViews, which I haven't tried. The parent RecyclerView having a linear layout manager and the child recycler view with grid layout manager.